# JavaScript accordion - problem with for loop inside for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I wrote javascript code for a simple accordion. The program works, but I have a problem that every time I load the page I have to double-click on heading (h2 tag), after that it works well and responds to one click. I don't know why it doesn't go into the second for loop immediately after the page loads?

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionItemHeading");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("textAccordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    console.log(i);
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        
        if (acc[i].classList.contains("active") && panel[i].style.display === "none"){
            panel[i].style.display = "block";
            console.log(i);
        }
        else {
            panel[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
  });
}
```

```css
.textAccordion {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">One</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>
            
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Two</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Three</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Four</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, your panels have `""` set as their `display` style.

The only issue was that the `if` condition failed because of this.

If you set `display: none` at the start of the first loop (before the event listener), the behavior is the one you're expecting.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordionItemHeading");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("textAccordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  panel[i].style.display = "none";
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        if (acc[i].classList.contains("active") && panel[i].style.display === "none"){
            panel[i].style.display = "block";
            console.log(i);
        }
        else {
            panel[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
  });
}
```

```css
.textAccordion {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">One</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>
            
  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Two</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Three</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

  <h2 class="accordionItemHeading">Four</h2>
  <p class="textAccordion">Aenean pretium lorem sit amet sapien ornare, sit amet consequat mauris fringilla.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, that was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go to the second for loop after the page loads is because second for loop is inside event handler. So event handler will be called when you actually click something, `.addEventListener("click", () => {})` so when you first click it then it goes to your event loop, and executes the callback with your for loop.